# Compiler error while running project in Xcode having MapKit framework

Tags: ios

[image: Xcode ScreenShot of error]

I'm in serious trouble. I created a test project with mapkit framework  and it worked fine as desired. Now the problem is that when i integrate the same code with my original project i get these errors after the BUILD.
" ignoring file /Users/*****projFolderPath*****/MapKit.framework/MapKit, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)"

I have added the framework of MapKit and done the exact things which are working in my test project.

I have even deleted the build and tried a lot more things but with out any success.

How to go about from this error?

Comment: When you say "added the framework", how did you do that?  Does it show up correctly if you look in the link section of the target's Build Phases tab?

Comment: in the Xcode project i added the frame work by clicking on the project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Click on the + mark and then select MapKit.framework

Yes it looks perfectly fine in the Build phases tab. Usually whenever the frameworks are not added properly they show up in red color. But mine MapKit framework is in prefect shape.

Comment: Don't know what is the error yet.. still clueles

Comment: Definitely a mystery.  The only other things that come to mind are: Product->(Option)Clean Build Folder... if you haven't tried that, and build for a device and see if there are similar messages.  (I assume that's a simulator build since it says i386.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of the simulator. Run it on a device , it will work perfect